# Download speed of an app at the App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

I think the title is self-descriptive, but I'll describe it more precisely here: What I mean by "Download Speed of an app" is when you click in the download button of an application, at the `Purchases` tab we'll see the app downloading, like this:

[image: download]

Where can I see the download speed of OS X El Capitan, in the case of this image?

---

This might have been asked before, but I don't find it anywhere. 
I tried clicking the progress bar, but nothing is displayed, the only thing that the `Purchases` tab displays is the app, downloaded size, and time remaining.

This question takes me to another question: How do I know what's all that's being downloaded? I ask this because I feel the download speed is very slow sometimes, and I'd like to know what are the apps that are downloading stuff...

Comment: Are you concerned about App Store download speed, your general internet download speed or something else? In case of download speed, did you measure/observe throughput over time or is it just a recent event you are looking at?

Comment: @patrix I edited the question, but to give you a short answer: Yes, about the App Store speed of an app download.

Comment: @IconDaemon I clarified the question

Comment: Well, I think it highly depends on your ISP, but I just downloaded Xcode 7.2, about 4 GB and it took 20-30 minutes.  Not sure, I was multitasking other downloads/installs, but on that order of speed.  Took some time to install.  Apple Canada.

Comment: I realize thats not a how to measure answer, but it is an order of magnitude answer - it was fairly speedy and probably near my ISP limits.

Answer (score 1):

The download speed on the App Store depends on two things: speed and size. If you have a DSL connection (the average connection is around 128kbps to 3000kbps (3mbps)), it is going to be very slow to download an app. If you have fiber optic internet (which can range from 10mbps to a Gigabit) it is going to be a **hell** of a lot faster.

If you are downloading El Capitan, which is 6.2GB, and you are downloading on a 5mbps connection, then it will take almost 3 hours to download.

You should take a Speedtest [here](http://www.speedtest.net/) and see what your speed is, you can also see if you are getting what you paid for. Go to [this link](http://www.download-time.com/) and input your **download speed** here.[image: Download time calculator]

I have found that if you have inputted DNS servers in System Preferences, remove the DNS servers and that should make it a little faster.

Happy downloading!

Cheers

EDIT: If you want to see how fast it is downloading, try Rubbernet which shows how much bandwidth a process or an app is using. Another app (which I use), is iStat Menus. It only shows processes that are using most of the bandwidth. The process that you are looking for is "storedownloadd" which downloads apps on the App Store. Sorry for misunderstanding you.

Comment: Mekul, I don't want to know what my internet download speed is, what I want to know is at what speed an app is beign downloaded, for example, when you download something at google chrome you can see the download speed...

Comment: @feniixx I updated my answer, sorry for misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1):

You can check in Activity Monitor. Go to the Network tab. You can only see the total download speed of all apps together. For the individual apps you can see the number of Bytes and packages received. That should give you an idea of how fast the download is going.

Comment: So basically you're telling me there's no way to see the download speed of a single app at the App Store?

Comment: You could try `software update -d -v`